# Como forçar o Prettier a sempre colocar um ternário em multinível

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, prettier

Estou criando uma aplicação usando o VSCode como IDE e, para fazer o *lint* do código, estou usando o [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) e o [GTS (Google TypeScript Style)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gts) onde em um local do código tenho algo semelhante a isso:

```js
const sampleTernaryResult = 2 + 2 === 4 
  ? "it's not an even number"
  : "não é um numero impar";
```

No arquivo do ESLint, eu configurei de forma que ele sempre coloque o ternário como multi-linha, assim:

```js
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/",
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0,
    "max-len": ["warn", {"code": 160}],
    "multiline-ternary": ["error", "always"]
  }
}
```

Ao salvar o arquivo o ESLint faz a formatação para o ternário multilinha. Ao fazer isso, o Prettier detecta que está incorreto e se eu salvar novamente ele volta o ternário para uma só linha. O que eu preciso fazer para que o Prettier não faça essa correção? Há alguma configuração para fazer com que o Prettier ignore isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você *pode* estar misturando as coisas. Prettier é um *formatador* de código extremamente opinativo, de modo que possui [pouquíssimas configurações](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) relativas à formatação do código. [Mais detalhes.](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html)

Desse modo, você há de escolher qual ferramenta utilizará para formatar:

- Prettier, de modo a desativar todas as regras de formatação do ESLint que podem causar conflito — como é o caso de `multiline-ternary`.
- Não utilizar Prettier, deixando a formatação a cargo das regras de estilo que o ESLint fornece.

É categórico: você não pode utilizar Prettier e regras de formatação específicas do ESLint, caso contrário encontrará conflitos em diversas situações durante o desenvolvimento do seu projeto.

Pessoalmente, eu acho que vale a pena deixar do jeito que o Prettier faz. Por muito tempo, a comunidade JavaScript foi muito fragmentado em questão de formatação. Ainda é, mas, com o Prettier, esse abismo tem diminuído, o que é decerto muito bom.

O Prettier fornece uma configuração do ESLint para desabilitar as regras de estilo que mais comumente causam conflitos. Chama-se `eslint-config-prettier`.

Lembre-se:

- Primordialmente, o ESLint tem função de fazer o *lint* do código.
- Já o Prettier tem a função primordial de formatar o código.

É claro que podem ter algumas ocasiões que o Prettier faz algo absurdo. É o caso de utilizar o comentário mágico `// prettier-ignore` antes de uma expressão para impedir a formatação padrão.

Comment: Estava querendo usar o gts (Google Typescript Style) e ele em si usa o prettier. No final das contas eu dei um reset no meu projeto e coloquei o preset "standard-with-typescript" que resolveu meu problema.